# PSI and index do not match / Error:Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugManifest'

Tags: android, ionic3

I work on an app with the framework Ionic and when I run my app thanks to Android Studio these errors appear :

On the Event log :

> PSI and index do not match: PSI and index do not match

On the message gradle build :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/fb_app_name" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/fb_app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" />
        <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance, 
Caroline

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I am fixed the issue by changing the  gradle both (v7 and v4) compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0+" to "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0+"